# Creating a categorical variable from several dummies?

Tags: r

I'm using the GSS data on sexual orientation, which had three categories (homosexual, bisexual, straight). I wanted to further disaggregate this by gender (gay man, lesbian woman, bi man, bi woman, straight man, straight woman).

I created a dummy variable for each of these categories, but now I'd also like a category variable for gender&sexual orientation (eg, 1=straight man, 2=bi man, and so on ....). Is there any way I can do this either from the original 2 category variables on sexual orientation and gender, or from my dummies? I've seen information on creating a dummy variable from category variables, but never the other way around.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataset?

Comment: You could just `paste` them together, but you might be better using two variables as you can then test for each variable in isolation too.

Comment: Yup, and after pasting them together you can pass as.factor then as.number to turn them into numbers if you so wish.

Answer (score 0):

use `dplyr`:

```
df = data_frame(x = sample(c("gay", "bi", "straight"), 100, replace = T), y = 
sample(c("male", "female"), 100, replace = T))

df <- df %>% group_by_all %>% mutate(G = group_indices())
```

This will give you a separate index for each unique group